# Update preexisting telegram menus using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot

I am building a telegram bot that will automatically add messages to preexisting menus in a bot ( created by **Manybot**, not with python ) once they are uploaded to a specific channel.

I spent a week or so trying to find a way to update preexisting menus but it can't manage to find a solution.

even when I try to run an infinite loop to monitor any messages to the bot ( using any telegram-python library out there ) i get this error :

```
Conflict: can't use getUpdates method while webhook is active; use deleteWebhook to delete the webhook first
```

and i am forced to delete the webhook , which will in turn disable every command i added to the menus and need to create another bot

I would really appreciate any help .

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not related to existing webhooks, it's the fact that each bot token can poll / webhook only once.

In other words, you can't have two scripts running with the same bot token, regardless if it's long polling or a webhook.

This is a limitation of the Telegram Bot API.

You can only run your own script when the manybot version of your bot is paused, stopped, turned off, etc. The getUpdates method will reject new connections with the same bot token.

You can either use a second bot token to use other commands if your setup allows it, or use the MTProto API with frameworks such as Pyrogram or Telethon.

Comment: thank you for the reply , i took your advice and tried telethon ( again ) and it worked but only if only me send messages ( i tried it on other devices )  ,it only returns an event if only i use it ?

Comment: That sounds it's related to how you coded your script. Which would be another question